# Is multithreading allowed on Spark/YARN?

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Since YARN is responsible of managing the resources of Hadoop applications, like cores and processes, is a YARN application allowed to create new threads ?

I refer mainly to Spark applications running on YARN resource manager. I know that if you create a new thread no errors are thrown but, is it safe ?

Comment: What do you mean create new threads? I believe Spark supports being run on YARN and even has options like num-workers.

Comment: I mean creating "new Thread()" and run custom code on a single worker. I don't care whether it is a best practice or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reply to myself. YARN controls resources like memory and cores, not threads. Cores are controlled by changing OS specific parameters when creating containers (process affinity). Then, the JVM is running using a specified number of cores and you can create as many threads as you want.